# Magento: How to hide child-categories products from being displayed on top category?

Tags: php, magento

In magento, all products from a child-category is being displayed on top/parent categories. For example, i have this set of categories:

```
Fabric
- Cotton
---- Shirts (1)
--------Half Sleeves (5)
```

So in total i have 6 products, and when i click on **fabric**, it shows all 6 products along with sub-categories.

I don't want this, i want to only list categories and don't want to pull products from child-categories.

So, i want a method or way that can list only child-categories when i click **Fabric**. And only list 5 products when i click half-sleeves.

Btw, all of my categories are already set to **Is Anchor = NO**.

Here is the snippet from app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

```
$_cat = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$curent_cat = $_cat->getCurrentCategory();
$curent_cat_id = $curent_cat->getId();
$parentId=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($curent_cat_id)->getParentId();

$categoryid = $parentId;//$_category->getId();

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');


$i=0; 
foreach ($collection as $_product) {........}
```

Any ideas?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

hello Aamir Siddique  try this function to get child every time, so when click on fabrics you have to pass id of fabrics to this function to get it's child category, here i am giving function so you can get children array,

```
function get_child($category_id)
{
    $id=$category_id;
    $i=0;
    $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($id);
    foreach ($children as $category)
    {
    $data["cat_data"][$i]["id"]=$category->getId();
    $data["cat_data"][$i]["name"]=$category->getName();
    $i++;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try change `Display Mode` of `Fabric` category to `Static block only`, then create a static block in which contains link to child categories?

Comment: yes `display mode` is already set to `static block only`. But i am not sure what you mean about `creating a static block in which contains link to child categories?`

Comment: If `display mode` `static block only`, so what is content will be display when customer click on `Fabric` category? You should create a CMS Static Block and assign to that category. Your static block will be display when customer click on `Fabric` category. The content of Static Block may be is list of links to Fabric's child categories or something else.